# Mongodb cannot use dot notation on referred documents?

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb's dot notation feature is quite cool, but I find that it seems not work on referred documents.

So dot notation can only be used in embedded arrays or subdocuments, am I right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot notation [may only be used to query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation) within the fields of a single document (or [sub-document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#read-operations-subdocuments)). It cannot be used to refer/query on other documents.

While there are times where I thought it would be an interesting feature to add, it's generally easy to create an alternative schema design that doesn't require it for "queryability" or performance.